# Deterministically generate public/private key from a seed for asymmetric encryption

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to implement a client side method to encrypt data in transit, and the key will be generated from client side with node.js

Right now, i am stuck in a situation that, it seems only RSA key can satisfy the asymmetric encryption for my use case, but the key can only be generated randomly but not deterministically. However, I want the client to be able to regenerate the key from a seed (e.g. a long hash) every time they log on the system, and the key must not be stored on a server.

Is that any workaround or other encryption method that suits my use case? Did some research and came across the npm package below, which said to be able to go the above with RSA.

is there some potential risk for the implementation?

Comment: Does the client know the public key of the server? do the clients have unique identification? What are the risks?

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72047475/11783958), you can use [`node-forge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) to create a "rigged" [prng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) that consistently returns an appropriately formatted seed rather than a pseudo-random value.

Code could look like the following, grabbing user's input and generating a long hash from it:

```js
import forge from "node-forge"

const userInput = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'

const md = forge.md.sha256.create();
md.update(userInput);
const seed = md.digest().toHex());

console.log(seed) // output: d7a8fbb307d7809469ca9abcb0082e4f8d5651e46d3cdb762d02d0bf37c9e592
```

Then creating the PRNG and generating the keys deterministically:

```js
// "Rigged" PRNG
const prng = forge.random.createInstance()
prng.seedFileSync = () => seed

// Deterministic key generation
const { privateKey, publicKey } = forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair({ bits: 4096, prng })
```