# How to generate safe RSA keys deterministically using a seed?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, deterministic

How do we use a **mnemonic list of words** as a seed (like we have been become accustomed using cryptocurrency wallets) to be able to recover a private key in case it gets lost, accidentally erased, or stuck on a broken device?

This could be useful for e2e encryption between clients: the keys are supposed to be generated on the client, only the public key will be shared with the server.

Users could be **regenerating the keys offline** when needed, as long as they are able to provide the mnemonic again, obviously to be stored safely and offline.

The mnemonic seed should be long enough to provide a safe amount of entropy.

[Some Q&A appear to be very outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156275/generate-rsa-key-pair-in-javascript-based-on-a-password): how can we achieve this in Javascript/Typescript, possibly using maintained libraries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Solution: `bip39` and `node-forge`

To quote [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/how-can-one-securely-generate-an-asymmetric-key-pair-from-a-short-passphrase/1665#1665) which has guided me to achieve this solution:

> in this scenario, the resulting public key is, by nature, public, and
> thus can serve for offline dictionary attacks. The attacker just has
> to try possible passwords until he finds the same public key. That's
> intrinsic to what you want to achieve.

We can assume that [128 bits of entropy should be enough](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6149) for preventing this kind of attacks, in the foreseeable future, however we can fortunately decide how strong our mnemonic will be.

##### 1. Generate mnemonic

First of all we can generate a mnemonic using the [`bip-39`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bip39) JS implementation.

```js
import { generateMnemonic } from "bip39";

const mnemonic = generateMnemonic(256) // 256 to be on the _really safe_ side. Default is 128 bit.

console.log(mnemonic) // prints 24 words
```

##### 2. Create deterministic PRNG function

Now we can use [`node-forge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) to generate our keys.
The `pki.rsa.generateKeyPair` function accepts a [pseudo-random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) function in input. The goal is getting this function to NOT compute a pseudo-random number (this would not be *deterministic* anymore), but rather return a value computed *from the mnemonic*.

```js
import { mnemonicToSeed } from "bip39";
import { pki, random } from "node-forge";

const seed = (await mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic)).toString('hex')

const prng = random.createInstance();
prng.seedFileSync = () => seed
```

##### 3. Generating keypair

We can now feed the `generateKeyPair` function with our "rigged" prng:

```js
const { privateKey, publicKey } = pki.rsa.generateKeyPair({ bits: 4096, prng, workers: 2 })
```

##### *Et voilà!*

We now have safe and deterministic RSA keys, directly generated on the client and restorable with the same mnemonic as a input.
Please consider the risks involved using deterministic keys and make sure your users will **NOT** store the mnemonic online or anywhere else on their client (generally, it is suggested to write it down on paper and store it somewhere safe).

Comment: Genuis solution

Comment: Actually, workers:2 enables non-deterministic prime number generation (you can see it here in the comments https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/2bb97afb5058285ef09bcf1d04d6bd6b87cffd58/lib/prime.js#L150). So the key generation itself is not deterministic. But for now it seems impossible to disable workers, due to this line https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/2bb97afb5058285ef09bcf1d04d6bd6b87cffd58/lib/rsa.js#L1722